# OAuth2 Redirect to the URL I defined? How can I redirect to the user page

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, redirect

I have an overview of the OAuth2, If the user approves of the access, The application server redirects the user to the the redirect url with the code I will use to get the token.

But mostly for all the third party application, after login, it will redirect to the user page. That's correct because user do not need to get their code. But if the page is redirect to the user page. How to redirect to the page I defined to get the code?

So we will get the code from the redirect url and use the code to get the access token and redirect again to the user page(with the header contains the token) that with the user content?

Comment: it takes it as special argument and upon successful redirect that particular argument is returned unchange hence you can then use to redirect to user page...sory i forgot the name of the argument to be used...

Comment: @SSH Sorry I cannot get your idea, can you explain it more clearly? I am very confused about this step. All the document is talking about get the code from the URL and use the code to get the token but didn't talk deep about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`state` parameter is an opaque string that is round-tripped in the protocol; that is to say, it is returned as a URI parameter in the Basic flow, should include the value of the anti-forgery unique session token, as well as any other information needed to recover the context when the user returns to your application, e.g., the starting URL.

Have a look [Oauth2 state parameter](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect?hl=en#state-param) to get more clear understanding.